# は vs.では in こんなうるさいところでは勉強ができません

Tags: particle-は, negation, scope

> こんなうるさいところ**では**勉強ができません。

How is the meaning of the sentence above different from the meaning of the one below?

> こんなうるさいところ**で**勉強ができません。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

は in a negative sentence can indicate the scope of negation. Compare:

> こんなうるさいところで**は**勉強ができません。
>   こんなうるさいところで勉強**は**できません。

Both can be used almost interchangeably in most situations, but the former can imply "I can't study in such a noisy place (but I could study in other places)." while the latter "I can't study in such a noisy place (but I could do other things here)." (i.e. in the former, こんなうるさいところで part is negated, and in the latter, 勉強(できる) is negated.)

(こんなうるさいところで勉強**が**できません doesn't sound natural)