# には contrast in following sentence

Tags: grammar, translation, particles, negation, scope

> ジャックは誕生日会に行きます。
>
> 彼はメグのために誕生日のプレゼントを買う必要があります。
>
> ジャックはあまり多くのパーティにはいきません。
>
> 彼は緊張し、 何を買おうかと思います。

What is the role of には in ジャックはあまり多くのパーティにはいきません? The only usage of には I know of is for contrast but I can't identify what contrast is being made here.

Secondly, I have trouble translating あまり多くのパーティにはいきません. Does it mean "doesn't really go to alot of parties"?

Answer (score 4):

The contrastive は can mark the scope of negation. 
(From the context, the は in ジャックは is the topic/thematic particle.)

Compare:

> ジャックは多くのパーティに行きます。-- 肯定文/affirmative sentence
>   ジャックは今日**は**パーティに行きません。-- 今日 is negated. (implying he might go on another day)
>   ジャックは車で**は**パーティに行きません。-- 車で is negated. (implying he might go by some other vehicle)
>   ジャックはパーティに**は**行きません。-- パーティに is negated. (implying he might go to some other place)

As you can see, は marks/highlights the negated element in a sentence.

Back to your example...

> ジャックはあまり多くのパーティに**は**いきません。

Here, あまり*多くのパーティに ("to so many parties") part is highlighted and negated. It implies Jack goes to parties, but doesn't go to **that many** parties.

Regarding this usage of は, these threads might help:

- [Why is the topic marker often used in negative statements (ではない, ～とは思わない)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1077/9831)
- [は vs.では in こんなうるさいところでは勉強ができません](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65337/9831)
- [The difference between は and を?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/49081/9831)

---

*あまり as an adverb is followed by a negative word (here ない), meaning "not so~~, not very~~, not really~~". For more on this, see this post on [Negative Polarity Items](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/16060/9831).